# How to copy 75gB to a series of DVDs using freeware?

Tags: backup

I do not want archive or compress, just a straight copy, where the program keeps prompting for a new DVD when it needs one, until all is backed up.

A bonus if it optimizes to use the least number of DVDs.

Looking for Windows freeware (http://hcidesign.com/dvdspan/ looks ideal, but is not free)

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: How do you plan on splitting the file/s?

Comment: I could not find anything. For $12.50, I would just pony up the money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Burn to the Brim](http://bttb.sourceforge.net/), but [Size Me](http://lars.werner.no/?page_id=2) seems better.

Just so you know this type of thing is called "[disk spanning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_spanning)."